# ¿Cómo obtener elemento web con Selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

estoy teniendo problemas para obtener información de una página WEB, el cuál pude recopilar de manera exitosa otros elementos.
Sin embargo hay una línea que no pude obtener la información que necesito.

He intentado los distintos métodos otorgados por Selenium, cambié algunas comillas `""` pensando que pudiese ser esto, sin resultados favorables.

Código página WEB

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado obtener la información con estos códigos:

```
#TEST FULL XPATH
error = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/div")

#TEST NOT FULL XPATH
test = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="oReportCell"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/div')

otro = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#oReportCell > div:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td > div")

otra = driver.find_element_by_id("oReportCell")
```

El resultado que me muestra:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

El resultado esperado que busco:

```
Texto: RESPUESTA: -1 | CLAVE ERRÓNEA
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leyendo a profundidad me dí cuenta que se trataba en un iframe, lo que me llevó a escribir el siguiente código:

```
def respuesta():
    #ENCUENTRA EL PRIMER IFRAME
    driver.find_element_by_id('ReportFramectl141')
    #SE CONECTA A PRIMER IFRAME
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/span/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/span/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/iframe'))
    #ENCUENTRA EL SEGUNDO IFRAME
    driver.find_element_by_id('report')
    #SE CONECTA AL SEGUNDO FRAME
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/frameset/frame[2]'))
    #VARIABLE QUE ENTREGA EL SEGUNDO FRAME COMO TEXTO
    texto_resultado = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/div').text
    #TERMINA LA CONECCIÓN DEL FRAME
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    return texto_resultado

#FUNCION QUE ALMACENA LOS POSIBLES ERRORES Y LOS DEVUELVE

def lista_de_errores():
    error1 = "RESPUESTA: -1 | CLAVE ERRÓNEA"
    error2 = "RESPUESTA: -1 | NÚMERO DE OT INCORRECTO"
    error3 = "RESPUESTA: -1 | DV INCORRECTO !!"
    return error1, error2, error3

#VARIABLE DE LA LISTA DE ERRORES
errores = lista_de_errores

#EN CASO DE ERROR DEVUELVE EL ERROR O MUESTRA EL RESULTADO
if resultado == errores:
            print('Intente nuevamente!')
        else:
            print(resultado)
        continue
```

Entregando el resultado que esperaba. Saludos!